# Android SDK is Missing and not let me to install

Tags: android, macos, flutter, sdk

I want to install Android Studio for flutter
after installing Android studio, It must install SDK automatically but it says it is installed and after that it says android sdk is missing

[This is when I want to install SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OOt8.png)

Comment: I guess you're installing it at different folder, were android sdk has no rights to access it. 

Try different folder where user has can access it fully.

Comment: I did but it is same

Answer (score 0):

Go to SDK manager and add the path of the SDK location that you have installed

[image]

Comment: Android SDK Location is Empty ?

Comment: add the SDK path where you installed the sdk

Comment: the sdk must be installed automatically, but it is not installing